# Client getting XML Schema errors using schema that works fine for me

Tags: xml, xsd

I am not an XML expert by any stretch of the imagination but I know a little about it.

I have created a Schema document and a sample XML document that is validated by it.
I have used Altova XML Spy 2004 rel 4 to create and validate both the XML schema and XML document.

I have sent the XML smaple doc and XML Schema to a client who has tested it and it works fine.

I sent it to a second and they are reporting errors. Specifically:

[image]

If you can't read the image text it says:

```
Code Description                                                   File
-1   The length constraining facet is prohibited for 'Date'.       sample_xml201108.xml
-1   The length constraining facet is prohibited for 'Date'.       xml201108.xsd
-1   The MaxLength constraining facet is prohibited for 'Integer'. xml201108.xsd
-1   The MaxLength constraining facet is prohibited for 'Integer'. xml201108.xsd
-1   The MaxLength constraining facet is prohibited for 'Integer'. xml201108.xsd
```

The associated XML Schema code is:

For the date type:

The code causing the error is:

```
<xs:simpleType name="dateType">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
      <xs:length value="10"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

For the first Integer element:

```
<xs:element name="x_no" nillable="true">
   <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
         <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

For the second Integer element

```
<xs:element name="y_no" nillable="true">
   <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
         <xs:maxLength value="16"/>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

For the third Integer element:

```
<xs:element name="z_no" nillable="true">
   <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
         <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Any help with understanding why the one client is getting these errors when neither I nor another client have this problem would be gratefully received.

The client with the error is using Liquid XML Studio 2009 and has tried it with Altova XML Spy 2009.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XML Schema specification part 2, related to data typing (see for example the date datatype here http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#date) tell you the allowed facets for each XML Schema simple type. maxLength is not allowed for integer, you should consider using `totalDigits` (constrains only the significative numbers, not leading zeros) or `pattern`, 
for example :

```
<xs:element name="z_no" nillable="true">
   <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
         <xs:totalDigits value="10"/>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Same remark for Date : consider using the `pattern` facets instead of length.

Comment: Vincent, many thanks for your answer. Are you saying that the XML schema I wrote is now deprecated so worked in my environment as it was an older version of XML Spy?

Comment: The recommandation I told you about is from october 2004. It's possible that your XML Spy from 2004 is not totaly aware of it.

Comment: That's the impression I got. Thanks for the clarification and the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that a schema is valid, you need to do more than run it through XML Spy, especially a version as old as XML Spy 2004. Your example, showing that XML Spy fails to detect the incorrect use of the 'length' facet with an xs:date, is a perfect illustration of why.

Comment: Thanks, to be fair I did get it validated elsewhere and it seemed OK but given the time constraints and technology I was given to use the obsolete MaxLength facet got through. It's still in testing so no harm done but it gives me a concrete reason for my client to upgrade to the latest software versions.